# How to find the hidden download link of a file?

Tags: php, download

I want to write a flexget config file to download some subtitle files form http://subs.sab.bz/ The site provides rss feeds for its new releases. Unfortunately, the link provided will open a download page, but will not get the file.

I browsed through the code of the download page and the download link in the code will open  the download page again when pasted in the browser will re-open the download page again... Clicking on the download button, though, will start the download of a rar file.

I want to get to the link for downloading this rar file(containing the subtitle files)

Is there a way to bypass this behavior. I read that usually a script on the server will provide the direct link of the download, I want to get that direct link.

Alternative solution will be a linux (Ubuntu 11.10 preferred) download manager, which is able to read RSS, trigger download based on filter( specific shows) download the file to specific location, and unpack it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of things they have configured their site to prevent people from doing exactly what you're trying to do. Any attempt to hit the download link with a download manager or request it directly won't work.

Comment: Dont like the answer, but at least you save me time trying to do something not possible(it seems). Thank you

Comment: @deckoff it might be worth your time checking the page headers as the site loads up - there are a few browser plugins that would do this for you like live http headers.